# How to format a list within a list to a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I tried to look around for this solution but have been unable to find it. I have this line in my code:
`AccountDetails.append([row[0],str(row[1]),response["status"],[],0,0,0,0,0])`

I am attempting to save this as a CSV file like this:

`with open(today + '.csv', 'ab') as File:
     writer = csv.writer(File)
     writer.writerows(AccountDetails)`

The problem I am having is with the list I have within AccountDetails (element 4). When I print what I currently have to a CSV file, it prints row[0] in column 1, row[1] in column 2, etc, but for the list `[]` it prints all of its contents into one cell. What I would like is all the information in that list in their own columns. Essentially the CSV looks something like this:

`**ID           Status       SubStat               List**
123              on          connected        12pm,ID33,Yes/No,etc`

where Info is my `[]` list, and I want it to look like this:

`**ID           Status       SubStat           TheTime     Serial     App   **
123              on          connected         12pm         ID33     Yes/No`

Not sure if this would be relevant, but here is the sublist, it is reading data from another CSV file called reader:

```
`my_reader = list(reader)

for row in my_reader:        
    for detail in AccountDetails:
        if(detail[0] == row[1]):
            detail[3].append([row[0],#3#0 subdevice id
                              row[3], #3#1 subdevice model
                              row[4], #3#2 subdevice status,
                              row[6],0] #3#3 last contact
                               ) #3#4 Delivered, used later

            break`
```

Comment: Why do you append a list in detail[3] instead of ´´detail[3] = ([row[0], row[3], row[4], row[6])´´?

Comment: @CunivL I updated the post. it is reading from another CSV, this is the best way I thought to do this. I am pretty new to coding, and very new to python, so if there is a better way Id be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correclty, you want to unpack the inner list into the outer list so the content gets distributed over separate columns in the resulting CSV. In This case, try `[..., *inner_list, ...]`:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> row = ["first", "second", "third", *lst, 0, 0, 0]
>>> with open("test.csv", "w") as f:
        csv.writer(f).writerow(row)
```

The resulting CSV will look like this:

```
first,second,third,1,2,3,0,0,0
```

as oposed to this without the `*`

```
first,second,third,"[1, 2, 3]",0,0,0
```

In older version os Python, this is not possible, though. Then you will have to contruct the list as

```
>>> row = ["first", "second", "third"] + lst + [0, 0, 0]
```

Of course, both of these approaches will "destroy" the inner list when unpacking it, i.e. `row[3].append(...)` does no longer work, as `row[3]` now is not the inner list, but the first element of that list (or the first element after it if it was empty). Either, populate `lst` before unpacking it into `row`, or add it without the `*` and flatten the list before writing it to CSV:

```
>>> row = ["first", "second", "third", [], 0, 0, 0]
>>> row[3].extend([1,2,3])
>>> [x for l in (a if isinstance(a, list) else [a] for a in row) for x in l]
['first', 'second', 'third', 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do. I am using python 2.7 and tried to do the above method and came across an error with my append. `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'` Even when I removed the append, the data all printed in one cell(and was the incorrect data without the append)

Comment: @Daftyler Because now `accountDetails[3]` is not a list. The list has been unpacked, and at index 3 is the first element of that list (or the next element after the list if it was empty). Can't you add the elements to the list before unpacking it to the `row`?